# Symbolic Logic: Specifying Quantity with Existential Quantification

Tags: logic, notation

Say I want to specify quantity with the existential quantifier—for example, $\left(\exists ! x\right)\left[\psi\!\left(x\right)\right]$ means "there exists a unique $x$ such that $\psi\!\left(x\right)$".

How would I symbolically state something like “there exist exactly $n$ $x$ such that $\psi\!\left(x\right)$” (for an arbitrary $n$)?

For example, “there exist exactly two real roots to the equation $x^{2} + 5x + 6 = 0$” (or, equivalently, “there exist exactly two real numbers $x$ such that the property $x^{2} + 5x + 6 = 0$ is satisfied”).

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively,
$$\left(\exists x_1 \exists x_2 \dots \exists x_n:\left(\bigwedge_{1\le i\le n}\psi(x_i)\right) \land \left(\bigwedge_{1\le i<j\le n}(x_i\ne x_j)\right)\right)\land \neg \left(\exists x_1 \exists x_2 \dots \exists x_{n+1}:\left(\bigwedge_{1\le i\le n+1}\psi(x_i)\right) \land \left(\bigwedge_{1\le i<j\le n+1}(x_i\ne x_j)\right)\right)$$

Comment: If I have interpreted this correctly, you’re defining the existence of each $x_i$ and conjoining them and predicating their inequality (ie, there are $n$ $x_i$s such that $\psi\!\left(x\right)$ that are distinct). Quite intuitive and elegant, I definitely agree—thanks :)But is there a notational shorthand?

Comment: You can define the first part of this as a sentence $\operatorname{Exists}_n$ so the above becomes $\operatorname{Exists}_n \land \neg \operatorname{Exists}_{n+1}$, but I don't think there is a shorthand for this.